# Will WebAPI 2 IHttpActionResult with StreamContent automatically enable compression?

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api

In the code below it mirrors a azure blob stream over the wire to clients. Will webapi enable compression on the stream automatically or would I need to add this manually to the `BlobResult` action result?

```
public class BlobResult : IHttpActionResult
{
    private readonly CloudBlockBlob blob;

    public BlobResult(CloudBlockBlob blob)
    {
    }

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await blob.FetchAttributesAsync();

        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content = new StreamContent(await blob.OpenReadAsync())
        };

        response.Content.Headers.LastModified = blob.Properties.LastModified;
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(blob.Properties.ContentType);

        return response;
    }
}
```